# How to catch exception thrown by a Kafka partitioner

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams

I have a project with Spring Boot and Kafka Streams.

I extended the existing DefaultPartitioner as described in this tutorial: https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/writing-custom-partitioner-for-apache-kafka-77935e46064e

I just needed to add some validation on the key.

If the key isn't correct, then an exception is thrown.

I'd like to catch this exception, log it and exit.

I tried to catch the exception as follows:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private StreamsBuilderFactoryBean factory;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void start() {
        factory.getKafkaStreams().setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            factory.stop();
            System.exit(1);
        });
    }
}
```

To test this code, I just changed the partitioner so that it always throws:

```
@Override
    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes,
        Cluster cluster) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

My expectation is that the exception is catched but it actually doesn't and I don't know why.

Comment: can you put a reproducer in github ?

Comment: Unfortunately not because that's business code, but it looks from my tests that the exception handler catches only expections thrown in the stream and in the partitioner. I think that we're not supposed to thrown in the partitioner...

Comment: reproducer means simpler version of your project, no need to put your business code, but kafka spring versions are important and what kind of exception handler you used. Actually most of the time while preparing a reproducer you see better of the situation and solve it.